# Windows 10 Action Center won't open

Tags: windows-10, action-center

I got this problem yesterday after updating to the latest Windows 10 update, but after restarting my Action Center won't open at all. Everything works fine, but the Action Center looks like it's loading for 2 seconds and then does nothing. I tried all Google solutions useClass+PowerShell development command + `sfc /scanow` + health image + new user + rolling back to a previous restore point before the update, but nothing fixed it. log field shows this message:

```
Faulting application name: ShellExperienceHost.exe, version: 10.0.18362.145, time stamp: 0x5ce50c77
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.ActionCenter.dll, version: 10.0.18362.145, time stamp: 0x5ce4ce4d
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000009ccf5
Faulting process id: 0x22cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d51a3649b0eed3
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\ShellExperiences\Windows.UI.ActionCenter.dll
Report Id: ab79c840-5746-4884-8e43-f8187d6ba395
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.18362.145_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Comment: I would uninstall the patch.

Comment: i uninstalle  the latest win 10 update and back to old restor point and nothing fix that problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the latest Windows 10 update and restoring Windows 10 back to a previous restore point will fix the problem.

Comment: yes i tried this solution i back to an old restore point before latest update and nothing fix the problem same error log file and im gonna wait until next quality update i hope microsoft fix that problem , thanks for the reply